# C# Наследование

Tags: c#, наследование

Решал задачу по наследованию на: http://skills.itvdn.com/

Конкретно условие звучит так:

*После объявления класса Base создать такой класс Derived, унаследованный от Base, чтобы его field1 по умолчанию имело значение “derived.f1”, а field2 – значение "base.f2".*

Казалось бы ничего сложного, всего лишь дописал конструктор и присвоил в нём полям нужные значения.

```
using System;

namespace Less03_task01
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            Derived inst = new Derived();
            Console.WriteLine("f1 = {0}\tf2 = {1}", inst.field1, inst.field2);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Base
    {
        public string field1 = "base.f1";
        public string field2 = "base.f2";
    }

    class Derived : Base
    {
        public Derived()
        {
            field1 = "derived.f1";     
            field2 = "base.f2";
        }
    }
}
```

Но *** та там, задача решена не верно. Залез в подсказки там было написано:

*"Или можно перекрыть поле field1 новым полем с таким же именем (используйте 
ключевое слово new)."*

Что это значит и как это использовать в решении задачи?

Comment: Вроде, и без перекрытия задача кажется правильно решенной. Другое дело, что скорее всего ее не приняли из-за того, что ты в наследнике выполняешь присваивание к field2.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Base
{
    public string field1 = "base.f1";
    public string field2 = "base.f2";
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public new string field1 = "derived.f1";
}
```

Термин «перекрытие» означает, что в производном классе будет присутствовать такой же член, как и в базовом классе, и перекрывать его. Другими словами, в производном классе будет новый, никак не связанный с базовым классом (в отличии от виртуальных) член с совпадающим именем.

```
var d1 = new Derived(); 
var d2 = (Base) new Derived(); 

Console.WriteLine(d1.field1); // derived.f1
Console.WriteLine(d2.field1); // base.f1
```

Перекрывать члены базового класса можно и без оператора `new` но в таком случае компилятор выкинет предупреждение. Другими словами, оператор `new` просто выключает предупреждение компилятора.

Comment: О, спасибо большое

Comment: @АндрейАбиев что бы признать ответ правильным, можно нажать на галочку